# How to alter the name of downloadable excel sheet of webform

Tags: 7, webforms

**Issue:**

When I click on the link of`webform` **Download** as shown in below screenshot the default name of excel sheet before save to local disk appears like `localhost_worklog.xlsx` but I want something like `localhost_worklog_02172017.xslx` which is appended with `_<current time>`.

**SCREENSHOT:**

[image]

**EDIT:** After using **iLLin's** answer

[image]

**Problem:** How can I alter the name of `localhost_worklog.xlsx` before save?

I am using `drupal 7.53`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to change the `$node->title` on the loaded object for the webform.  That filename uses that title, so I am assuming you have a webform title of "Localhost Worklog".

The problem with that is you only want to change the node title, when you are downloading the webform (or atleast running through that process).

You have two options (I think).  You could implement a `hook_entity_load()` function and then check if the URL is

node/%webform_menu/webform-results/download
**or**

node/%webform_menu/webform-results/download-file

```
function MYMODULE_entity_load($entities, $type) {
  if (arg(2) == 'webform-results' && (arg(3) == 'download' || arg(3) == 'download-file')) {
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
      $entity->title = $entity->title .'_'. now();
    }
  }
}
```

[Docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_load/7.x)

The other way I can think of is altering the page callback with a `hook_menu_alter()`, changing the title there and then calling their function to return the form or download file with the updated node object to include the time appended to the title.

### EDIT

From reviewing your update, it seems it's changing the title too soon on that page.  So I think you will need a combo approach.  Using `hook_entity_load` and `hook_form_alter`.  The point is changing that title in the $node object that is passed around for download.  So try this.

```
/*
 * Implements hook_entity_load().
 */
function MYMODULE_entity_load($entities, $type) {
  // Change the node title to include the time when downloading.
  if (arg(2) == 'webform-results' && arg(3) == 'download-file') {
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
      $entity->title = $entity->title .'_'. now();
    }
  }
}

/*
 *  Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == WEBFORM_DOWNLOAD_FORM_ID) {
    // Change the node title that is passed around for download.
    // @TODO: Check to make sure this is correct.
    $form['node']['#value']->title = $form['node']['#value']->title . '_'. now();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I was able to change filename accordingly but how can I retain the original title on dashboard.Pls see my edit.

Comment: You need to only change that title before the download process.  What does your code look like?  It shouldn't "save the node title" and it should only change it on those two pages.  You may need to do a form_alter or try another location in the code.